# ¿Cómo guardar datos haciendo dos columnas al momento de dar click?

Tags: python

tengo un problema tengo el siguiente código que me da las coordenadas x,y.
¿Cómo podría guardarlo en un archivo txt. pero formando columnas?
Necesito guardar estos datos como un dataframe pero formando unas cuatro o seis columnas.

Alguna ayuda

El código es:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor, Button
from numpy import random
import math


x, y = random.rand(2, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p, = plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

cursor = Cursor(ax,
                horizOn=True, # Controls the visibility of the horizontal line
                vertOn=True, # Controls the visibility of the vertical line
                color='red',
                linewidth=1.0
                )
def onclick(event):
    x1, y1 = event.xdata, event.ydata




        print(x1,y1)
        file = open("Prueba.txt","a+")
        file.write("X:"+str(x1)+" Y:"+str(y1))
        file.close()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que un tabulador `\t` es lo que estas buscando, prueba de la siguiente manera:

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor, Button
    from numpy import random
    import math


    x, y = random.rand(2, 100)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    p, = plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

    cursor = Cursor(ax,
                    horizOn=True, # Controls the visibility of the horizontal line
                    vertOn=True, # Controls the visibility of the vertical line
                    color='red',
                    linewidth=1.0
                    )
    def onclick(event):
        x1, y1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
        print(x1,y1)
        file = open("Prueba.txt","a+")
        file.write("X:"+str(x1)+"\t Y:"+str(y1)+"\tMás Datos\tUltimo dato.\n")
        file.close()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: existen otras formas?

Comment: Probablemente sí existan muchas más, sin embargo sé que existe una librería llamada: PrettyTable, puedes darle un vistazo.

Comment: Por una extraña razón no lo puedo usar

Comment: Prueba con `texttable`

Comment: @JhoubertRincon podrías añadir una explicación del por qué de tu código?

Comment: \t es un tabulador, basicamente lo que haces es crear un espacio del tamaño de los espacios faltantes para el proximo multiplo de 4.